# Почему не работает символ перехода на новую строку в коде матлаб?

Tags: matlab

Символ перехода на новую строку присутствует, это "\n",но он не работает, что тут не так?

```
fileid=fopen('C:\Users\User\desktop\our_file.txt','w')
dd='aga\n'
fprintf(fileid,'%s\n',dd)
dd='ogo'
fprintf(fileid,'%s\n',dd)
fclose(fileid);
```

Comment: У вас Windows. Попробуйте `\r\n`.

Comment: ура благодарю за ответ он мне помог